# Adding rule lines to lines in a text box (multi line)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, textbox, multiline

Does anyone know of a way to add Rule lines to a multi-line text box control?

I was thinking of the writers pad style faint blue lines under each line of text, filling the entire control. (Not just underline the stuff typed in a rich text box.)

Just as a blank large text box it looks rather bland. I thought someone out there might know of a custom control, or a way to draw a line under each text line.

Cheers.

Comment: A TextBox control does not permit mixing graphics and text.  It is not remotely a WebBrowser or word processor.  You can make text look like a line by picking a Unicode character, ChrW(&H2500) gets the job done.  If you want to change the color as well then you need RichTextBox.

Comment: Are you doing it in web/desktop ??

Comment: Desktop. VB WinForms. That chr might be a good place to start, have something at the end that removed the instances from the string.
Food for thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick sample I threw together that should get you started:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private g As Graphics
    Private x As Long
    Private lineHeight As Long

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        g = Me.CreateGraphics()
        lineHeight = 20
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        g.Dispose()
        g = TextBox1.CreateGraphics()

        For counter As Long = lineHeight To TextBox1.Height Step lineHeight
            g.DrawLine(Pens.LightBlue, 0, counter, TextBox1.Width, counter)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

I'll leave figuring out the value of lineHeight and how to choose where to draw the first line up to you (also, don't forget the vertical rule for the lefthand margin)

HTH, 
Eric

Comment: @Josh Glad I could help.  Keep in mind that this is just a quick prototype and has plenty of issues.  To really do this right you'll need to take this nugget and wrap it up with any other logic you want in a custom user control.